# How to get the reverse percentage (not amount of reverse percentage)?

Tags: percentages

if 100 x 1.17 (17%) = 117, how can I know how many % I have to deduct 117 to get 100? Obviously, this is no more 17%.

The same can be applied if 100 - 10% = 90. Then how many % I have to add to 90 to get 100? Again, it is no more 10%.

I know how to calculate this, but I was wondering if there is a math formula for this? something as simple as `a*b=c => b=c/a`

Comment: Hint: if $100 \times 1.17 = 117$ then $117 \times 1.17^{-1} = 100$. What is $1.17^{-1}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use percentage of increase/decrease.

$$\frac{b-a}{a}$$

Where $a$ is the initial value and $b$ is the final value.

$$\frac{100-117}{117} = -\frac{17}{117} \approx -0.14523$$

Multiplying the value by $100$% gives the percentage. So, subtracting $14.523$% of $117$ from $117$ will give $100$.

Just remember that when $b > a$, the answer will be positive, so there is a percentage increase (must be added), but when $b < a$, the answer will be negative, so there is a percentage increase (which must be subtracted).

Answer (score 0):

Increasing something by $r\%$ means multiplying it by $1+r$ - a fact you seem to know.

In fact changing by  $r\%$ means multiplying it by $1+r$ even when $r$ is negative, so a decrease. To see that, think of "$25\%$ off"
 as "multiply by $1-0.25 = 0.75$".

So the simple formula you want to undo an increase of $r\%$ is to multiply by $1/1+r$. If you really need to separate out the actual percent change, it's just
$$
  \frac{1}{1+r} -1 = -\frac{r}{1+r}.
$$

To check that, note that it tells you that to undo a $100\%$ increase, which corresponds to $r=1$, you need a $50\%$ decrease.