# A is greater than B by 25% then by what percentage B is less than A?

Tags: percentages

> Q. $A$ is greater than $B$ by $25\text{%}$ then by what percentage $B$ is less than $A$ ?

**my approach**:

$A$ is greater than $B$ by $25$% then

$${A-B\over B}\times 100=25$$

$$A=B+0.25B=1.25B$$

Now, $B$ is less than $A$ by %

$$\frac{A-B}{B}\times 100=\frac{1.25B-B}{B}\times100=25\text{%}$$

Is my answer correct? I don't know where I am wrong.

Help me solve this question. Thanks.

Comment: $20%$ or $25%$ of WHAT  ???

Comment: thank you i got it @hamam_Abdallah

Comment: sorry it was a typing mistake thank you sir

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is not correct. You must take $\text{%}$ of B w.r.t. A as follows
$$\frac{A-B}{A}\times 100=\frac{1.25B-B}{1.25B}\times 100=\frac{1}{5}\times 100=20\text{%}$$

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem in your question. In Q   you say

> $A$ is greater than $B$ by $20\%$

but then in your attempt you say

> $A$ is greater than $B$ by $25\%$.

I will assume the second statement is correct.

I think the best way to think of percentage change is as multiplication by a factor. Then
"$A$ is greater than $B$ by $25\%$" means
$$
A = 1.25B .
$$
So (solving for $B$)

$$ B= \frac{A}{1.25}=  \frac{1}{1.25}A = 0.8A = (1-0.2)A
$$
so $B$ is $20\%$ less than $A$.

For a slightly more abstract argument, see
[How to get the reverse percentage (not amount of reverse percentage)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2990062/how-to-get-the-reverse-percentage-not-amount-of-reverse-percentage/2990087#2990087)

Comment: thank you for your answer i got it

Answer (score 0):

In such questions is most important to clearing which number we are taking as 100%.

When we say $A$ is greater than $B$ by 25% of $B$ then $A=B+B\cdot 0.25$

When we say $A$ is greater than $B$ by 25% of $A$ then $A=B+A\cdot 0.25$

Same for reverse.

Answer (score 0):

Working with percentages is always, always, always a multiplication, never, never, never and addition or a subtraction, like in this case:

```
A = 1.25 * B
B = 1/1.25 * A
  = 0.8 * A
```

And 0.8*... means, subtract 20%.