# What is the relationship between percentage increase and percentage decrease?

Tags: probability

Specifically, I am curious if there is a formula that models how much of a percentage increase would be required after a certain decrease to arrive back at the original number.

For example:
A 70% decrease of 100 is 30. What formula shows us what the percentage increase will need to be in order to arrive back at our original value of 100?

Thanks

Comment: What is the contrary of multiplying a number by $(1 - \dfrac{70}{100})$ ?

Comment: If you multiply $x$ with some number and you want to go back to $x$ then divide the result with that same number. E.g. if $100\times0.3=30$ then $30/0.3=100$. Personally I always avoid percentages.

Comment: If the quantity had been decreased by $d\%,$ then to raise it back to the original value requires a $$\frac{100d}{100-d}\%$$ percentage increase.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A is greater than B by 25% then by what percentage B is less than A?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3766063/a-is-greater-than-b-by-25-then-by-what-percentage-b-is-less-than-a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\Bigg(1-\frac{p}{100}\Bigg)\Bigg(1+\frac{\frac{100p}{100-p}}{100}\Bigg)=1$$

When $p=70$ you get $\frac{100p}{100-p}=\frac{7000}{30} \approx 233.33$. Note that many people get confused by large percentage increases and might not be able to tell whether this was more or less than tripling.

Answer (score 1):

First, remember that a percentage is just a fraction, that is $70\%=70/100=0.7$ .

And  a decrease of $70\%$ amounts to substracting $70/100$ times the original value, that is

$$y = x -  \frac{70}{100}x=  ( 1- 0.7)x =0.3x $$

In general, a decrease by some ratio $r$ amounts to multiplying the original number by $1-r$ (and an increase, by $1+r$).
Hence, to get back the original number you must divide by $1-r$.

Now, if you have a decrease $d$ and want to calculate the "takeback" increase $i$ that takes the value back to the original, you want

$$ 1+ i = \frac{1}{1-d} \implies i = \frac{1}{1-d}-1 = \frac{d}{1-d}$$

In our example $d=0.7$, $i=0.7/0.3=2.33.3 = 233.33 \%$

Notice that the takeback increase is very different from the original decrease.
However, if the decrease was small, then indeed $i \approx d$ (say, $d=1\%=0.01 \implies i=0.10101 = 1.01\% $)